# What is this Typescript explicit type casting using "as" really doing?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was just reading through this [example Angular test](https://stackblitz.com/angular/plvdrgebobr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.service.spec.ts) and saw some syntax I'd never seen before.

There is a unit test that declares a variable to custom type:

`let expectedHeroes: Hero[];`

And then it sets the value of that variable, but uses `as Hero[]` at the end, which I would think is unnecessary given that the variable was already typed:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  heroService = TestBed.get(HeroesService);
  expectedHeroes = [
    { id: 1, name: 'A' },
    { id: 2, name: 'B' },
   ] as Hero[]; //<== WHAT IS THIS?
});
```

So is that SECOND `as Hero[]` really doing anything, or would it be just fine without that second type declaration?

Comment: Type casting in typescript is like in any other strongly typed languages except you have no runtime guard against incorrect(imcompatible) casts because javascript

Comment: Given that `let expectedHeroes: Hero[]` was declared above, if the objects in `expectedHeroes` have all of the properties that the `Hero` class defines, then `as Hero[]` seems unnecessary here. However, if the objects in `expectedHeroes` contain a subset of the properties that the `Hero` class defines, `as Hero[]` could be a way of providing only the properties you need for the test, while keeping the compiler happy (it wouldn't matter at runtime).

Comment: @FrankModica that is the answer, [Hero.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/testing/ts/src/app/model/hero.ts) has a clone method. You should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `let expectedHeroes: Hero[]` was declared above, if the objects in `expectedHeroes` have all of the properties that the `Hero` class defines, then `as Hero[]` seems unnecessary here.

However, if the objects in `expectedHeroes` contain a subset of the properties that the `Hero` class defines, `as Hero[]` could be a way of providing only the properties you need for the test, while keeping the compiler happy (it wouldn't matter at runtime).

**Edit:** @ProfessorAllman has noted that the `Hero` class has a `Clone` method, which seems to support what I wrote above. The tester may not want to mock that method in the test if they are only testing the other properties.

Comment: Compiler will throw an error if you try to cast a `Partial` of certain object to the main interface. This would make sense if `as Partial<Hero>[]` was used, but isn't the case

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa check out this example. It seems to cast fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Hero%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20expected%3A%20Hero%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexpected%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'My%20name'%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%20as%20Hero%5B%5D%3B

Comment: yep, it works but is incorrect. You are forcing some type so the compiler stops complaining, but the data is partial. If the code is patched to avoid compiler errors, then, why use typescript?

Comment: You are right, but my point was to explain why someone might do this, and I've seen it done to reduce verbosity during tests by only providing the subset of properties needed for the test. While I agree it's not the "right" way, if you provide completely wrong types or wrong names for the subset of properties you'll still get an error, so it's somewhat safe.

Comment: That's also the first time I've seen `clone()`. Why do that instead of just setting the properties in the constructor? Would you ever do this in a real project?

Comment: @redOctober13 In this case I'm not sure, but it's often a convenience method so if you already have an instance of `Hero`, you can do `hero.clone()` without manually copying properties over.

Comment: @FrankModica: cool, thanks. so for copying an instance; is it the same as `Object.assign({}, myObjectInstance)`?

Comment: `Object.assign` will do a shallow copy, so deep copying might be a reason to have a custom `clone` method (or you could use a library for that). But also, if you copy over functions with `Object.assign`, those functions might have closures over other data which shouldn't be used in the new object. So a custom clone method might help with something like that as well. You probably won't see these kinds of issues in frameworks like React, since they stick to plain data objects (without methods) and immutability. But for rich classes / objects, sometimes methods like this make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The array is an rvalue who's type cannot be deduced (array of what?), that's why the assignation fails as strong types are expected on both sides of the assignation.

Imagine the situation when you assign an empty array:

```
expectedHeroes = [];
```

How does TypeScript know the type of the array? no way to guess. You need to explicitly specify it:

```
expectedHeroes = [] as Hero[];
expectedHeroes = <Hero[]>[];
```

Now the same happens with objects. If you do this:

```
expectedHeroes = [{"something": 123}];
```

TypeScript can deduce multiple interfaces from there. Again, explicit type is needed. I personally recommend doing this:

```
expectedHeroes = <Hero[]>[ ... ]
```

As it makes intellisense smart about the type when writing the contents (and suggests you the properties)

Those "casts" are doing nothing but telling the type, they have no runtime impact

Comment: I would also stress that it has no runtime behavior, a common misconception is that casting to a class builds an instance of that class which is not the case

Comment: @ivan: I realize the value in typing, I'm just wondering what, if any, purpose there is in BOTH typing at declaration `let expectedHeroes: Hero[]` AND instantiation `expectedHeroes = [...] as Hero[]`.

Comment: The definition is `let expectedHeroes: Hero[]; ` , so the type is inferred when you assign it a plain Jane object array and all the type checking/intellisense happens already without needing `as`. My gut is telling me this is for self documenting code and to make it explicit to the programmer what type it is without having to go back to where it is declared.

Comment: @redOctober13 in this case the array is an rvalue who's type cannot be deduced by the compiler (array of what?), that's why the assignation fails as strong types are expected on both sides

Comment: Ah I was wrong, the full [Hero.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/testing/ts/src/app/model/hero.ts) has a method clone, so the `as` is making it so that you don't have to define the clone method in each of your object literals

Answer (score 1):

If there were no functions declared in your Hero class, then the cast would not be needed as the compiler would see your object literal as assignable. Your casting solution will work as long as you don't try to call `hero.clone()` on any items in the list.

Some examples:

```
class Hero {
    id: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(id: string, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let hero: Hero;

// The "right" way to do it
hero = new Hero("1", "Superman");
console.log(hero instanceof Hero); // true

// Not actually a Hero, but compiler will let it slide
// because it's an assignable object. Note that it does
// not convert the object into a Hero, just tells the
// compiler to ignore the fact that it's not.
hero = { id: "2", name: "Batman" };
console.log(hero instanceof Hero); // false
```

Now if we add more than just properties to the class things change a bit.

```
class Hero {
    id: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(id: string, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    clone() {
        alert('cloning ' + this.name);
    }
}

let hero: Hero;

hero = new Hero("1", "Superman");
hero.clone(); // works!

// This won't work because if the type system thinks
// the object is a Hero, it will allow hero.clone(),
// which does not exist.
hero = { id: "2", name: "Batman" }; // compiler yells!

// Now let's cast it to a Hero, overriding the compiler's
// checks
hero = { id: "2", name: "Batman" } as Hero; // compiler is fine w/ it

// But now the compiler can't catch other problems down
// the line.
hero.clone(); // runtime error: clone is not a function!
```

In non-test code, `new Hero` is the way to go and let the compiler do it's job. For test code, using an assignable object literal and bypassing the compiler check is fine as long as your code a) doesn't care that it's actually not an instance of the class and b) there are not functions declared on the class.